# javascript: how can I create a slow for...in loop

Tags: javascript, loops, for-in-loop

I'm building my own slideshow. I'd like to iterate over the members of an object, with an observable pause between each iteration.

Using setInterval,I've come up with this:

```
for (key in ob) {

setInterval(
    function (){
    console.log("Key:", key);
    console.log("Value:", ob[key]);
    }, 2000

        ) 

}
```

However, this doesn't work. It dumps logs the key/value pairs instantly, where my expectation is that there would be an interval between each operation.

How do I do the iteration with a pause between each operation?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it like that at all.

Try this:

```
var keys = Object.keys(ob);
var index = 0;
setInterval( function(){
    console.log( keys[index], ob[keys[index]] );
    index = ( index + 1 ) % keys.length;
}, 2000 );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DgAPw/

An example that doesn't roll around but instead stops once everything has been processed:

```
var keys = Object.keys(ob);
var index = 0;
var timer = setInterval( function(){
    console.log( keys[index], ob[keys[index]] );
    index++;
    if( index >= keys.length ) {
        clearInterval( timer );
    }
}, 2000 );
```

Comment: +1 You may clear the interval if all keys have been processed.

Answer (score 0):

Create a self recalling timeout for example:

```
function slowLoop(){
   setTimeout(function(){
   // Do something

   slowLoop();
   }, 2000);
}
```